# load external property file from classpath

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a maven project and have the following files:

```
mapping.xml file in /src/main/resource/xml
```

I have an XSLT file defined in /src/main/resource/xsl/foo.xsl

In foo.xsl, I have the following snippet:

```
<xsl:variable name="props" select="document('mapping.xml')"/>
```

I am struggling with how the document function reference the mapping.xml. I can only get it to work if I move the mapping.xml to the root of the project.

If the mapping.xml is in the /src/main/resource/xsl, then XSLT will not see it.

How can I tell XSLT to look in the classpath or the relative path?

This is using XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Who is "we"? I always use "please" and "thank you".

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<xsl:variable name="props" select="document('../xml/mapping.xml')" />
```

Comment: That doesn't work. By default, document function is referencing the base of the project. So by doing ../xml/mapping.xml, it's going down a level. There must be a way to configure it to look at the classpath of a project or relative path to where the XSL is.

Comment: @CharlieLee It does work for me. I am not sure what "the base of the project" or" the classpath of a project " mean in the context of XSLT. There is no "project" here; the document() function resolves a relative URI using the stylesheet's location as the base (unless told otherwise - see: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#document). So it actually goes UP from the `xsl` folder to the `resource` folder and from there down to the `xml` folder and to the `mapping.xml` file in it.

Comment: Working in a maven project. So there is a defined structure. ie. src/main/resource, src/main/java, which sits in the root of the project. The XSL file is sitting in the src/main/resource directory. The project classpath is therefore src/main/resource which is how a maven project is structured. For some reason, the XSLt document () is referencing the root of the project, in this case, foo-project. It needs to be pointing at /foo-project/src/main/resource.

Comment: The XSLT file doesn't "know" any of that. I don't know why you think that it "*is referencing the root of the project*". However, I see that *now* you say that the "*XSL file is sitting in the src/main/resource directory*". That's not what you said in your original question, so perhaps that's why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: **Note**: if it's true and your XSLT really finds a document located in another directory (not the directory where the XSLT itself is located)  when you use `document('mapping.xml')` then you have a non-conforming behavior. Perhaps that's a feature of the Maven tool, but then your question is not about XSLT.